# Jackson JSON jars aren't working in Karaf

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I have a very simple route that has a bean that import jackson-core and jackson databind.

I have never got these Karaf errors before and dont know what to do.

The left is my JBOSS developer POM jars. 
The top right are the Jackson jars in Karaf.
The bottom right is the Karaf exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did not deploy the jackson bundles in karaf. The dependencies in the pom only apply for build time. Together with your usage of the jackson classes they are used to create the Import-Package statements in your bundle Manifest.

These statements then tell karaf what you need at runtime but they do no auto install it. So try to install the jackson bundles with their mvn urls. Alternatively you might find them in one of the camel features.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the karaf listing of active bundles, you should see that the only active `jackson-core` bundle has bundle version  `2.6.3`.

From the error message, we can see that the framework is looking for a version of the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` in the range `[2.8,3)` .

Since it happens to be the case that version `2.6.3` of `jackson-core` exports version `2.6.3` of this package, the resolver can't find a match.

Incidentally, using only data current as of early March, there have been three releases of that package that introduced potentially breaking changes:

```
 new_version | old_version | version_delta | differ_delta | severity  
-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------
 2.8.2       | 2.8.1       | MICRO         | MAJOR        | Incorrect
 2.9.0.pr1   | 2.9.0       | CHANGED       | MAJOR        | Incorrect
 2.9.2       | 2.9.1       | MICRO         | MAJOR        | Incorrect
```

Version 2.8.1 of the this package is definitely backwards binary compatible (since the contents are bitwise identical :-)

There were an additional three releases with potentially breaking changes in the range  `[2.6,2.8]`, so you should make sure that any bundles using the currently deployed version are unaffected by any potential changes.

Note that if you deploy an updated bundle, currently wired consumers won't be affected until they are refreshed, or the server is restarted.

(Why yes,yes I am currently working on analyses of the reliability of OSGI versioning for bundles on maven central).

Comment: Simon, thanks for the information. Can you please help me out and tell me how I can add the correct REPO for Maven to automatically install them into Karaf.?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this issue by installing following jackson bundles (in my pom i have used all these packages of version 2.9.9)

```
bundle:install mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.9

bundle:install mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9

bundle:install mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.9
```

and pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This solution helps me to run my bundle with Jackson packages.